# SKPayment wont be removed from default payment queue

Tags: ios, storekit

i have the problem that even though i call
`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];`
the payment won't be removed from the default queue.

I installed a paymentobserver on the default payment queue. When my payment observer is being connected to the default payment queue, it calls the

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

observers method and forces the transaction to be "repurchase" (not restored!!).

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

It was pretty weired, but the default payment queue isn't the payment queue, from which I want to "finish" the purchase.

So what helped me is that in the method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

after a transaction has been purchased, I remove the transaction from the queue, given in the delegate method.

That did it! Maybe the queue was still from a purchase I didn't finish.

Maybe it helps someone!!

Comment: Did you use removeTransactionObserver method in this case method? Sorry to bring up an old thread.

Comment: Yes, i remove the transaction observer of the default payment queue when the object is beeing deallocated. But the transaction observer object is only once beeing added to the default payment queue.

Answer (score 0):

finishTransaction: method not works during purchacing. (calling addPayment: ~ transactionState will be  "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchaced" or "SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed")

Transactions in default queue will not be dicarded even if the app terminated. When there is no transaction observer, default queue pauses all transactions. When there is a transaction observer, default queue resume all transactions. This is why that "repurchace" cause.

I think that there's no way to cancel transactions.

You shuld turn userInteractionEnabled off in all controlls during purchacing.

Does this helps you? Sorry for my cheep English.